# Performance of nvd3 for a lot of data

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, jqgrid, nvd3.js

I have an application where I have to draw a lot of small nvd3 charts inside a jqgrid table in my angular application. I am compiling the charts with $compile. However, I notice that the performance is getting slower as the number of data is increasing (it still takes pretty quick to draw 1 small chart, but to wait for the whole thing it takes a really long time)

I noticed that this is a known issue based on this [post](http://www.quora.com/Does-D3-js-work-efficiently-on-massive-amounts-of-data-200-million-rows-with-at-least-a-dozen-columns) since it's DOM manipulation. I tried several tricks like compiling the charts in turn, etc, but it still feels so slow. Is there a known workaround for this issue?

Comment: In general, using canvas instead of SVG will give you a performance improvement. This isn't really an option with NVD3 though as using SVG is hardwired throughout the library. So the short answer is no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to improve the performance. I am posting this to help other people that have same problem with me.

The problem is:
I made each nvd3 chart as small reusable component as angular directive, and as a result I need to call $compile when I draw it inside jqgrid.

$compile is really not the fastest method out there so removing $compile call and using `<svg></svg>` directly in jqgrid solves my problem.

So if you have performance problem and you're calling $compile, maybe the first thing to do is to remove that $compile call. I am pretty new to Angular so hope this helps others that are having same prob.

Comment: Hi blenzcoffee, I am experiencing the same problems using nvd3 Library. I am really new into angular and d3, So I wanted to ask you for more details, if possible, in your solution. I am trying to load a file with around 80.000 lines but its just too slow. Any help very welcome.